# What is the number of female employees in the company?

Tags: probability

> Among the 640 employees in a company, 60% of males and 50% of females are married. If a randomly selected employee is married, the probability that this person is a male is double the probability that the person is a female. What is the number of female employees in this company?

I am completely lost where I am supposed to start. The only thing I can think of is that this might be a combination problem with relative frequency and product rule involved somehow. I think this is the hardest part for me, not being able to even recognize what type of problem I am dealing with.

I don’t see the connection for where to start with the given fact that 60% of males and 50% of females are married fit into my given hypothesis to use as a combination, relative frequency, or product rule.

Comment: Have you heard of Bayes' formula?

Comment: Oh, yes I have....now that you mention it Bayes seems to fit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event that our randomly selected person is married.  Let $B$ be the event that our randomly selected person is male.

We are told $Pr(A\mid B)=0.6$ and that $Pr(A\mid B^c)=0.5$

Further, we are told that $Pr(B\mid A)=2Pr(B^c\mid A)$

We know from earlier results that $Pr(B\mid A)+Pr(B^c\mid A)=1$, so this tells us what $Pr(B\mid A)$ is.

Now, let $Pr(B)=x$.  We wish to find what $x$ is.

We know that $Pr(A\mid B)=\dfrac{Pr(B\mid A)Pr(A)}{Pr(B)}$ and that $Pr(A)=Pr(B)Pr(A\mid B)+Pr(B^c)Pr(A\mid B^c)$.

Plugging in values and completing the necessary algebra lets us find the value of $x$ from which we can now find the number of females in the company.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $ A $ is the number of males and $ B $ the number of females then:

$ A+B=640 $

Also assume $ x $ is the number of married males and $ y $ the number of married females then:

$ x/A = 6/10 $ and $ y/B = 5/10 $ because out of all males 60% is married and out of all females 50% is married

Finally because if someone is married the probability being male is twice the probability being female we know that the number of married males is two times the number of married females so $ x = 2y $

So you have 4 equations and 4 variables:

$ A+B=640 $

$ x/A = 6/10 $

$ y/B = 5/10 $

$ x = 2y $

so $ (A,B,x,y) = (400,240,240,120) $

hence the company has $ 240 $ female employees